# running select query with PDO and mysql not working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

i have been trying to get some data out of a mysql database using php's pdo but its not outputting any data at all, i know PDO is installed and working because i have run other query's fine. here is my code

```
<?php 
error_reporting(-1);

$db_host="localhost";
$db_username="mike16889";
$db_password="********";
$db_name="omni";

try {
    $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name", $db_username, $db_password);
}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo $e->getMessage();
};

try {
    $sql = $dbh->("SELECT * FROM jobdetails");
    $sql->bindParam(1, $_SESSION["workerID"]);
    $sql->execute();
} catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
};

$sql->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
while($row = $sql->fetchObject()){
    print_r($row);
    echo'</ hr>';
}

print_r($data);
?>
```

it outputs absolutely nothing, no errors and no data.

Comment: `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '{' or '$' on line 18`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forgot to write `prepare` in the following line

```
$sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM jobdetails");
```

Comment: great, thanx for that, i can't belive i didn't see that, i;ve been staring at that code for so long, and am new to PDO. i will accept your answer in 10 mins.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you suppressing errors while in development?

```
  $sql = $dbh->("SELECT * FROM jobdetails");   //dbh-> what?  any method name missing? guess
```

Should be

```
  $sql = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM jobdetails");
               ^
```

Comment: i'm not suppressing errors, according to [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) -1 should show every single error. but thanx for the answer as well.